# Casting a Variable BEFORE using

Tags: java, casting

I need to cast the following product into an integer. I know how general casting works BUT i need to cast the variable from double to integer before multiplying it.

I already tried to do:
int produkt2 = (int) (a * b * c * d * e * f * g * h * i * j);

```
    float a = 314.15e-2f;
    float b = 3.1f;
    double c = 0.000314159e4;
    double d = 3.14159;
    int e = 0x11;
    int f = 011; 
    long g = 11L;
    char h = '3';
    byte i = 127;
    short j = 128;

    int produkt2 = (int) ( a * b * c * d * e * f * g * h * i * j);
```

The result is = 2147483647
The correct result must be = 113019401088

The exercise says that i need to cast it BEFORE multiplying. I guess thats my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

```
long produkt2 =  ((int)a) * ((int)b) * ((int)c) * ((int)d) * ((int)e) * ((int)f) * ((int)g) * ((int)h) * ((int)i) * ((int)j);
```

Comment: Thanks firstly, 
The result came closer but it's not quite right. 
It should be: 113019401088
With your implementation i get: 1350251392

Im sure that the variables are right because i used them for other exercises as well and the result there is right.

Comment: That's quite strange. Are you sure the result must be of type `int` ? The maximum value allowed for ints is 2147483647, which is less than your expected result.  You can, however, get the correct number using `long` instead of `int`.

Comment: Yeah i got the correct answer by using long. Thank you very much i didn't think about that. 
And sorry about my mistake ! =)